# Is it possible to set Kafka to receive a message in the topic with the name of the file that is uploaded to Google Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-storage

The connector allows me to read only json, avro, bytes and string formats. But if a pdf file arrives that then needs to be processed by a script that is executed via an image associated with a cloud run, do you have any ideas on how to do it?

(without using pub sub to communicate with kafka)

Comment: You don't want to use cloud function trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following solution:

1. Use kafka connect to list gcs files specifically the kafka-connect-file-pulse connectors.
   https://streamthoughts.github.io/kafka-connect-file-pulse/docs/getting-started/
   [image]

2. You can play with the metadata from an uploaded file that will be published to Kafka and then use that filename message from a Kafka consumer from a client subscriber running on Cloudrun.

hope that help you